# Generate multiple different subplots of multiple lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot simple linear plots of my raw data, consisting of mathematical functions on the first column. On the first row I want to plot the base functions, consisting of linear plots of different sine functions. On each subsequent row I want to plot streamplots, consisting of the projection of each of these functions on each base function, so in the end I basically have a 12x6 matrix of subplots.
I'd also like to add titles to each subplots.

The problem I have that the streamplots and linear plots come from different data and I want to solve it with for loops.

I hope this isn't too confusing.

I got this so far:

```
functions = [c_f, l_f, pa_f, po_f,n_, log_f, sin, series_vl12, series_apr12, series_mlr202, ex_pn]

base_func = [sin1, sin2, sin3, sin4, sin5]


U = []
V = []
for i in sums_phi:
    U.append(r * np.cos(i))
    V.append(r * np.sin(i))

Y, X = np.mgrid[:101:1,:101:1]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,40))

for x, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(U, V)):
    plt.subplot(11, 5, x+1)
    #function(a, b)
    plt.streamplot(X,Y,i,j, density = 1 )

plt.show()
```

Which gives me the streamplots without the linear subplots of my raw data.

[image]

Comment: In your code you just plot the streamplots, where are your linear plots?

Comment: I already plotted them individually, but that's why I asked how I can append or insert them into this loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more line in your definition of the subplots to split your problem in two. First plot your streamplots and then plot your linear plots.

Here in made a small piece of code that you can adapt in your case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3)
axs = axs.ravel()

for i in range(6):
    axs[i].plot(x, x**0.5)
```

Gives me the first 6 subplots:

[image]

```
for i in range(3):
    axs[i+6].plot(x, x**2, c='r')
```

Then I can plot an other function in the last 3 subplots:

[image]

Hope it helps for your problem.